# Is there a limited number of merge levels html help can retain index/search items for?

Tags: merge, chm, html-help, robohelp

I created a RoboHelp html help project that merges three projects into a master project. Indexes and search terms work fine in the Master.chm.  However, this Master.chm gets merged into another "Super-Master" application that my application is a plug-in for.  After that merge, the sub help .chms items do NOT appear in index and search does not find them.  Is there a limited number of "levels" merged help will allow index/search to work?  Or is it more likely there is some other problem (ie. Super project doesn't use Binary index) or something?

Comment: Apparently one level of children is all that's feasible if you don't have full access to the ultimate master project.  I can make it work by editing the .hhp of the master, but in this case, i don't have control over that as it is a third party.

Answer (score 3):

Mostly it's the binary index. Please check following list of general tips from Rob Chandler's website:

1. All CHM files should be installed to the same folder.
2. You can install any number of Slave CHMs but the Master CHM must always be installed if you want the slaves to reference the master
   Table Of Contents.
3. Each project must enable the "Binary Index" in order for index merge to work.

   - A binary index will not be created if you select 1.0 as the version in the Compatibility box > Compiler tab > Project Options
     dialog or if the Create a binary index check box is cleared.
   - Rick Stone reminded that the Master index must contain at least one index term in order for the merge to work.
4. Similarly "Binary TOC" must be *disabled* otherwise merge will not work.
5. Include HHC works recursively, so you can have groups of optional modules.  I.E. HHC files including HHC files that include other HHC
   files and so on.
6. Merging of Index and ALink keywords. This does *not* work recursively,  because they do not know about the TOC inclusions. If
   you want to have a  unified Index or cross-module ALinks you have to
   tell every CHM file which others might be available belonging to the
   same project. Again: Do *not* merge yourself.
7. Another idea: If you have identical keywords from several files, HTML Help uses the `<title>` tags in the list of targets. We extended
   the title of each topic with the title of the module itself (the
   "book"), leading to:  `<title>This fine topic title (This fine book
   title)</title>`.
8. An include statement in a HHC file can refer to a standalone HHC file. The HHC file should be placed in the same folder as the CHM
       files.

Comment: Number (6) seems to be my problem.  Child.chm->Parent.chm->Grandparent.chm.  Each chm does have an index and binary index is checked on all 3 projects.  Parent.chm will see the index of child.  Grandparent will see index of parent.  But Grandparent will not see index of child.  Same goes for searching keywords.  Topics are fine.  What do you mean: "You have to tell every .CHM file which others might be available belonging to the same project"?  How do i do this?

Comment: I found this: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/670450?start=0&tstart=0 .  The final post gets this to work, but it requires the top level .chm file to have prior knowledge of all lower level .chms files.  This simply won't do for me, since i don't have access to the hhp file of the top level project (its a outside source application).

Comment: [Reverse Engineering](http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/reverse_engineering/reverse_engineering.htm) - but this is a hard way and the result isn't sure. Not tested - but note the [Recovery script](http://www.wvanweelden.eu/product-category/recovery-script) (now moved)

Comment: Thanks, but methinks i cannot do this.  The main application will do its own regenerate of the main .chm every time ANY component is installed (other 3rd parties) and this will therefore lose my changes anyway.